# Lenovo Ideapad N581 with 12.10 does not connect to WLAN

Tags: wireless, 12.10

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my new laptop Lenovo IdeaPad N581 MBA84GE - Ivy-Bridge i3-2370M 8GB 500GB, but it doesn't connect to WLAN. In 12.04 it didn't connect too.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across a [comment](http://www.notebookcheck.com/Test-Lenovo-IdeaPad-N581-Notebook.82561.0.html)  saying that there are N581 models with broadcom wireless chips. That reminded me on my own odyssey of getting the broadcom wireless working in my macbook.

Can you post the output of the following commands

```
sudo iwconfig
sudo dmesg
sudo lsmod
```

that should help figure out what wireless chip your laptop has and whether your linux is able to talk to it.

Regards,
Alec

PS: Please type `<pre>` before the commands outputs and `<\pre>` after, so the formatting is preserved and the text stays readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your F's on the top of the keyboard, one might be a wireless key. If there is a wireless key, click Fn (Bottom Left of keyboard) + the 'f' Key it will hopefully work. Then check your wireless connections and if your Router is there (Eg. BTHub3-Zq817) then success! If not, then I'm afraid I can't help any more. Hope it works!!!

Oh, also you can connect via cable.

Jago G.